# Woocommerce Page Setup Fields Missing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the Wordpress dashboard under Woocommerce > Settings > Advanced there are normally fields where you can link a page to a function (Cart, Checkout, My Account etc.)

For some reason mine have disappeared and all my old links now return a 404.

[See what I mean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55YuQ.png)

I can't find an answer anywhere on the web and I've tried everything I can think of. Anyone had a similar issue?

The issue seemed to appear after installing one of these plugins:

- [Woocommerce Upload My File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-upload-my-file/)
- [Easy File Upload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-upload-files-during-checkout/)

I have deactivated both but the issue persists.

I've tried:

- Other browsers
- De/Reactivating Woocommerce
- Restarting the Web Server

Is it possible for plugins to make modifications that remain even after they are deactivated?

Please help!

Edit: I've isolated it to being an error in the database. I exported my site with WP All-In-One Migration Tool and exported everything besides the database. Does anybody know which database entries relate to woocommerce settings?

Comment: "Is it possible f"or plugins to make modifications that remain even after they are deactivated?", Yes, that's why that every chenge to a stie should be done in a Test server first.
Anyway, have you tried to re-activate them? In Woocommerce>>Status>>Tools>>Create pages

Comment: Tried that too. Still nothing. I understand that I made an amateur move not testing. Just trying to find the best fix without having to rebuild the whole site.

Comment: Have u made any changes in core files or any other plugin u are using ?? Try to deactivate all plugin than check it is it working or else deactivate woocommerce delete files and download again ..

Comment: I’ve tried this. Deactivated every plugin. Exported the site without plugins. The error is linked to the database as if I export the site without the database everything ia fine